# Start Node-Red silent

Tags: bash, node-red

I want to start node-red via script two times with different settings.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starte Server 1" 
node-red -s /home/a/.node-red/settings.js

echo "Starte Server 2" 
node-red -s /home/a/.node-red/settings2.js
```

How can I start node-red silent like a background service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `node-red` is, but I'll assume it's a javascript interpreter and that its invocation is successful.

To launch multiple things in the background:

```
#!/bin/bash

# You don't actually need this, but its nice to have
die() {
    echo "$@" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

# List of all your settings
settings_files=( \
    "/home/a/.node-red/settings.js" \
    "/home/a/.node-red/settings2.js" \
)

# function to start node red plus extra output
# about whether or not that succeeded
launch_node_red() {
    settings_file="$1"
    echo "Starting node-red with settings file: $settings_file"
    node-red -s "$settings_file" || \
        die "Could not start node-red with $settings_file"
}

# for each of the settings files, start node red with
# that file and run it in the background
for settings_file in ${settings_files[@]}; do
    launch_node_red "$settings_file" &
done

# Comment this out if you want the current script to
# just return to the shell.
wait # for the servers to exit
```

Comment: (And node-red is an IBM prototyping tool for IoT, currently also being used in some production systems. It's a web-based graphical programming environment on top of an express.js server and features a wealth of ready-made and third-party modules for wrapping functionality for hardware and services. And no, I'm not an IBM employee :) But it is a fun tool... http://nodered.org )

Answer (score 0):

you can use ( &)& to background process.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starte Server 1" 
(node-red -s /home/a/.node-red/settings.js &)&

echo "Starte Server 2" 
(node-red -s /home/a/.node-red/settings2.js &)&
```

or you can use nohub or screen commands to start node-red in background and monitor it